# Certain comment styles within a block break re-indentation in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation, auto-indent

In Sublime Text 2, re-indentation (Edit -> Line -> Reindent)seems to bug out in the presence of certain comment styles in Javascript code. Only single-line C-style comments (`/* ... */`)work properly.

For example, consider this un-indented code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
/* Single-line C-style comment */
var $player = $('#player');
/* Multiple-line 
C-style comment */
var $player = $('#player');
// Single-line C++-style comment
var $player = $('#player');  
// Multiple-line
// C++-style comment
var $player = $('#player');        
}
```

Reindenting the entire block should result in this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    /* Single-line C-style comment */
    var $player = $('#player');
    /* Multiple-line 
    C-style comment */
    var $player = $('#player');
    // Single-line C++-style comment
    var $player = $('#player');  
    // Multiple-line
    // C++-style comment
    var $player = $('#player');        
}
```

Instead, it ends up like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    /* Single-line C-style comment */
    var $player = $('#player');
/* Multiple-line 
C-style comment */
var $player = $('#player');
// Single-line C++-style comment
var $player = $('#player');  
// Multiple-line
// C++-style comment
var $player = $('#player');        
}
```

As long as the single-line C-style comment appears first, it and the line following it both get indented. No matter what order the other comments appear in, none of them, nor the lines following them, receive indentation.

The real problem here is that not only does the indentation fail on those comments, but they also break any indentation that would normally work following the comment. Using the Reindent command on each individual line, even the comments, indents them properly.

Any clues on this behavior?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific, because I'm not seeing the behavior you are. Walk us through line-by-line what happens when you type what...

Comment: @bronze: I am also observing this behavior.  Running ST2 on OS X 10.7.  ST2 Reindent Lines acts up not only on JavaScript comments but also CSS, among others.

Comment: @MattDMo is certainly specific. Copy paste the code above, select all the code, press `tab` for indent and you will get the result. In other words, SublimeText seems not to be indenting comments correctly.